# Ubuntu 12 ufw not allowing connections even if it says Anywhere?

Tags: server, firewall, ufw

Currently I can't seem to connect to my Ubuntu 12.04 server unless I disable my ufw or if I do a "ufw allow ip_address".

When I do a "ufw status" I get the following:

[image]

I deleted the allow my ip_address and technically it should allow me to ssh into my server via that port. But it just times out. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As ssh uses port 22 by default and I only see port 8880 mentioned in the screenshot. Try the following,

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

If you would only want your own IP address access to ssh you could use,

```
sudo ufw allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to any port 22
```

Replace `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` with your own IP address. Please check if you have a static IP address and not a dynamic one. In general, before doing anything like this, make sure you have access to the console in some other way. Else you might end up locking yourself out.

From: [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Services)

Comment: but i changed my ssh port to 8880 ... which is why the screenshot shows that. also did a 'sudo ufw allow ssh' and that doesnt work neither as it added the port 22, but im not using that port. not sure why i cant connect.

Comment: "sudo ufw allow ssh" adds port 22 because the application is listed here, /etc/ufw/applications.d/openssh-server, the openssh-server still lists port 22 as the port to use. Still that only just explains why port 22 got added, not the issue you are having.

Comment: Did you ever set something like "ufw default deny outgoing"? Maybe try "ufw reset" followed by "ufw allow 8880" ?